# ParameterVailidation Failed When Sending List to DynamoDB

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a simple Python function on AWS Lambda that just puts some data into a DynamoDB table and as far as I can tell, I'm following the correct format as per the Boto3 documentation for the put_item() function. I'm getting the following error that I can't seem to debug:

```
"errorMessage": 
"Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter 
Item.GSRResults.L[0], value: 3.8, type: <class 'float'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
\nInvalid type for parameter Item.GSRResults.L[1], value: 3.4, type: <class 'float'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\... snip...
\nInvalid type for parameter Item.GSRResults.L[9], value: 3.3, type: <class 'float'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/index.py",
      39,
      "upload_test",
      "Item=item"
    ],
```

Here is the Python function:

```
def upload_test(event, context):
    if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
        info = event['body']
        item = info['Item']
        return respond(None, dynamo.put_item(
            TableName="TestResults",
            Item=item))
```

This is the JSON I am sending:

```
{
  "body": {
    "Item": {
      "UID": {
        "S": "U999999"
      },
      "PID": {
        "S": "P444444"
      },
      "GSRResults": { "L": [3.8,3.4,3.3,2.8,1.3,3.2,4.3,2.1,3.2,3.3] }
    }
  },
  "httpMethod": "POST"
}
```

Comment: DynamoDB does not allow inserting float values.

Comment: @Asdfg Thanks for your response. In the documentation one of the examples they give:  `"L": ["Cookies", "Coffee", 3.14159]`

Comment: Dynamodb does allow to store float value as Number.

Comment: that example may not be for Python. Python treats 3.8 as float while other may treat it as decimal. I guess but I could be wrong here.

Comment: If I change these values to int's or str's I still get the same error with a different type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following [Client.put_item](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item) example for the Client API:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

item1 = {
  "id": {
    "S": "1",
  },
  "name": {
    "S": "Testing"
  },
  "age": {
    "N": "22"
  },
  "grades": {
    "L": [ {"N": "3.50"}, {"N": "3.1415926"} ]
  }
}

client.put_item(TableName='test', Item=item1);
```

Or use the following [Table.put_item](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item) example for the Resource API:

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('test')

item2 = {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Testing2",
  "age": 22,
  "grades": [ decimal.Decimal('3.50'), decimal.Decimal('3.1415926') ]
}

table.put_item(Item=item2)
```

It's very easy to find that you are using a Resource-level object (such as [Table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table)) but accidentally looking at the Client-level API documentation because the methods unfortunately have the same names (e.g. `put_item`).

See a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272744/when-to-use-a-boto3-client-and-when-to-use-a-boto3-resource) on when to use a boto3 [Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html) vs a [Resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html). The key difference here is that the Resource API marshals/unmarshals data to/from native Python data types automatically, while the Client API does not.

Comment: This did it, thank you so much! This is my first time working with Lambda and DynamoDB so I'm still learning how to properly format all of the data. I guess when retrieving the data I would need to parse this list of dicts and get all the values in a list. Kind of inconvenient but at least this is working now.

Comment: so much time wasted - thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

The float values should be set as demical in Python.

**Import:-**

```
import decimal
```

**Set the value as decimal:-**

```
"GSRResults": [decimal.Decimal('3.8'),decimal.Decimal('3.4')]
```

[Dynamodb Type for Python](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html)

> For types that involve numbers, it is recommended that `Decimal`
>               objects are used to be able to round-trip the Python type.

Comment: I tried this and it's still complaining that the type is not dict.

Comment: I have tested it. It works fine for me. I don't have type "L" explicitly in the json string. My jsonString = {"storage_CACHE_KEY": "2", "GSRResults": [decimal.Decimal('3.8'),decimal.Decimal('3.4')] }